# SQL combine two query results 2

Tags: sql

Find the names of boats and colors of the boats as well as the names of sailors who have reserved ‘Green’ boats.

How can I combine them together?

```
select B.bname, B.color
from Boats B

select S.sname
from Sailors S
where S.sid in (select s.sid
                from Sailors s, Reserves r, Boats b
                where s.sid = r.sid and r.bid = b.bid and b.color = 'green');
```

I've tried this but I got duplicate

```
select B.bname, B.color, S.sname
from Boats B, Sailors S
where S.sid in (select s.sid
                from Sailors s, Reserves r, Boats b
                where s.sid = r.sid and r.bid = b.bid and b.color = 'green');
```

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 0):

You can use `join`. You should avoid using implicit joins for the best practice instead use ANSI `join` syntax as following.

```
select 
    b.bname, 
    b.color,
    s.sname
from Sailors s
join Reserves r
on s.sid=r.sid
join Boats b
on r.bid=b.bid
where b.color='green'
```

If above result gives you duplicates then you can use `distinct` as `distinct b.bname`